# How can i display video from VCAM-AR1335B (daA4200-30mci) using GStreamer?

Tags: camera, gstreamer, yocto, pylons, basler

I must to get video from VCAM-AR1335B (daA4200-30mci) by using GStreamer in owr Yocto distro, but when i try to execute follow command "gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink" i see in console:

"
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
"

but after that nothing will be happend, but the same command works with VCAM-AR0821B.

Also both cameras work with Pylon app from Basler.
I've built a Yocto distro via this manuals:
https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=MX8_Basler_Camera&release=mx8mp-yocto-hardknott-5.10.72_2.2.1-v1.1
https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=MX8_Basler_Camera&release=RELEASE_ZEUS_V3.1_DART-MX8M-PLUS

Can you help me with correct GStreamer command for getting realtime video from VCAM-AR1335B ?

I tried many commands for GStreamer, but all don't work

Comment: Try verbose output with `-v` option of gst-launch-1.0 command

Comment: I doubt if Basler camera is available in system as Video4Linux device just like that. Maybe mingle with official Basler camera source for GStreamer: https://github.com/basler/gst-plugin-pylon/